# SwipeRefreshLayout not obeying constraints

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a SwipeRefreshLayout containing a RecyclerView for a chat activity. I have its bottom constrained to the top of a linear layout at the bottom of the screen:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context="org.andrewedgar.theo.ChatRoomActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listFooter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listFooter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/chatRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listFooter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listFooter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageInput"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_msg"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_send"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_send"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

..but the SwipeRefreshLayout still takes up the whole screen and the messages appear behind the message input:

[image]

Is there a special type of constraint required for this to work?

Comment: use wrap_content for SwipeRefreshLayout instead of match_parent

Comment: Thank you for your response. That raises it a little bit from the bottom but it still sits behind the edit text

Comment: then instead of ConstraintLayout use LinearLayout that would help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the height of `SwipeRefreshLayout` to 0dp

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Why?

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/):

> You can set the view size to a ratio such as 16:9 if at least one of
>   the view dimensions is set to "match constraints" (0dp).

Also

> **Note**: You cannot use `match_parent` for any view in a `ConstraintLayout`. Instead use "`match constraints`" (0dp).